# Rails Belongs to with different column names

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing some voting software where a user gets to vote for 3 different entries. For the votes model I was thinking of something like:

> Votes:
>   Email Address - String
>   Verification Code - String
>   Verified - Boolean
>   First - Entry
>   Second - Entry
>   Third - Entry

Where Entry is another model in my rails application. How could I have a belongs to relationship for this? As i'd like to run queries like get the entries with the highest number of votes for first place. Is this the best approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**User Model:**

```
has_many :votes, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :entries, :through => :votes
```

**Entry Model**

```
has_many :votes, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :users, :through => :votes
```

**Vote Model**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :entry
```

Answer (score 0):

I would design the Vote object such that it contains just a user_id and an entry_id.  Then your application logic would enforce that if they've already voted three times, they don't get to vote again.  That way, when you query for the highest number of votes, you don't have to write special cases for the first, second and third entries.

As far as the belongs_to declaration, I would say that a vote belongs_to both User and Entry, and should be destroyed when either dependent object is destroyed, thus:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, :dependent => :destroy
    belongs_to :entry, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Comment: You should not specify this option on a belongs_to association that is connected with a has_many association on the other class. Doing so can lead to orphaned records in your database.

Comment: Oops, you're right!  That should be on the has_many associations on the other side of the relationships.  Your answer above is better than mine, and more complete, so I'll upvote it instead.